# Graph API Permission Sites.Selected Permission is not working for subsites

Tags: sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-app-registration

My SharePoint logical url is like below
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/parent/child/grandchild

where each site is a subsite of its parent. i.e

- `parent` is a subsite of `mysite`
- `child` is a subsite of `parent`
- `grandchild` is a subsite of `child`

i am trying to access a resource under the `grandchild` with an app registration. The app registration has the below app permission

[image]

i have followed [MS DevBlob's post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/) to add the app registration to the `grandchild` site. however I am getting the following error (status code `400`),

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "Operation not supported",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-09-28T15:13:59",
            "request-id": "c659387b-1ca1-4bd4-957d-49dcd189f314",
            "client-request-id": "5a0a2485-945d-6951-86fe-425b135d1184"
        }
    }
}
```

i get the same error while allocating the app registration to the `child` subsite. however, the operation becomes successful when I run it against the `parent` subsite.

possibly because of the above, I am getting an HTTP status code `403` whenever I try to run any API call under `grandchild`. Below is an example error while running the below get,

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/child/grandchild`

```
{ 
    "error": { 
        "code": "accessDenied", 
        "message": "Access denied", 
        "innerError": { 
            "date": "2023-09-28T14:55:27", 
            "request-id": "511ba36c-3d83-4865-8518-5469b4e3c25e", 
            "client-request-id": "511ba36c-3d83-4865-8518-5469b4e3c25e" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Is there any way to associate an app registration to a subsite (i.e to `grandchild`)? Do i need to run a command to make a subsite inherit app registration from its parent? Am I missing any additional privileges/API permission in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that, app registrations are **inherited** from parent sites to child sites by default. Adding app registration to **parent site** will automatically be available to all child sites, including grandchild.

I have one SharePoint site where I created **subsites** same as you like this:

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD application and added `Sites.Selected` **API permission**:

[image]

When I ran below graph query to add above app registration to site with **token** having **`Sites.FullControl.All`** Application permission, I got response like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/permissions
{
  "roles": ["read"],
  "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": "43b700cc-00b2-4637-888b-xxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": "SriSharepoint"
    }
  }]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to get **grandchild** details by running below query, I got the **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/m365xxxxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/child/grandchild
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got **Access denied error** when I tried to access different site, other than site for which permission created:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/m365xxxxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/demoparent/demochild/grandchild
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, check how you added the app registration to site with what **`siteID`** and make sure to access **same site** for which permission is created.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. when you run post for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/permissions what is the `siteid` you are using. it is the `parent` or the `mysite` one?

Comment: It is parent `siteid`. You can run this: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/` and find siteID [here](https://i.imgur.com/9jaNt9f.png)

Comment: i tired with new sharepoint and created parent > child > grandchild. I can give permission up to parent and it works. I can query upto parent but getting 403 for child and grandchild.

Comment: Could you run this query `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/child/grandchild` with token having **Sites.FullControl.All** permission and check `siteID` of grandchild and parent are same or not?

Comment: this is the `id` value for each call,  `sites/parent` - `mysite.sharepoint.com,496440f7-d0cd-417c-a0c9-b72fdef347a3,6d44b8d9-a5f5-4d46-9bd5-3fce324e2a05`. `sites/parent/child` - `mysite.sharepoint.com,496440f7-d0cd-417c-a0c9-b72fdef347a3,f7e90bea-7cb3-4382-b961-592d33b98b3e`. `sites/parent/child/grandchild` - `mysite.sharepoint.com,496440f7-d0cd-417c-a0c9-b72fdef347a3,053babf9-f791-4711-97dd-01edb38baea1`

Comment: Use `496440f7-d0cd-417c-a0c9-b72fdef347a3` as **siteId** to send post request for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/permissions

Comment: post to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/496440f7-d0cd-417c-a0c9-b72fdef347a3/permissions` works but i am still getting 403 when i use the identity to perform a get to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/child/grandchild`

Comment: Same call for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/parent/child/grandchild` should work as permissions are **inherited** from parent sites to child sites by default. In my case, post to parent `siteId` works for `/sites/parent/child/grandchild`.